# Should I edit a question if its current answers lose relevance?

Tags: discussion, edits, questions

Answers sometimes connect to the question in many ways:

- quoting the question
- using words contained in the question
- using the same code

But sometimes it would be better to rephrase the question or change punctuation without changing the meaning. Then any current answers lose relevance and are harder to follow because they reference the question less.

What should we do in these cases? Edit both the question and the answers? Leave them alone? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

If rephrasing the questions significantly improves it, without *invalidating* the existing answers, I'd definitely change it. Try to apply the same edit to the quoted parts in the answer, but if that's not possible, it's still not a big problem. Answers often quote comments or other answers as well. Make sure your edit summary (in case of a suggested edit) reflect the fact that you're updating the quotes because the question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the question can be easier for people to understand.

Comment: Good point! So should I edit both the question and the answers without a guarantee that all the edits will be accepted? I assume that the edits will make the question easier to understand.